# Python not recognizing variables in while loops

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm new to programming with python/in general. The goal is to produce a random number and have the user guess the number, telling the user if their guess is correct, too high, or too low. For some reason, it says "too low" no matter what I do. Here's what I have so far:

```
import random
numberGenerated = random.randint (1, 5)
userInput       = raw_input("Enter a number between one and five: ")
numberEntered   = int(userInput)
while numberEntered > numberGenerated:
    print "Your guess was too high"
    userInput  = raw_input("Enter a number between one and five: ")
while numberEntered < numberGenerated:
    print "Your guess was too low"
    userInput  = raw_input("Enter a number between one and five: ")
else:
    print "You're Correct!"
```

Comment: Please fix thy indent

Comment: There's also a flaw in the logic of the program...

Answer (score 0):

You should use proper logic...
try this and ask if you have any doubts

```
import random

numberGenerated = random.randint (1, 5)

userInput = raw_input("Enter a number between one and five: ")

numberEntered = int(userInput)

while numberEntered!=numberGenerated:

    while numberEntered>numberGenerated:

        print "Your guess was too high"
        #print numberGenerated
        userInput = raw_input("Enter a number between one and five: ")
        numberEntered = int(userInput)

    while numberEntered<numberGenerated:

        print "Your guess was too low"
        #print numberGenerated
        userInput = raw_input("Enter a number between one and five: ")
        numberEntered = int(userInput)

print "You're Correct!"
```

Comment: Hint: what happens if the user enters a guess that is too low, then one that is too high?

Answer (score 0):

an other way to do this is by keeping a boolean value. This makes your code better structured and readable.

```
import random

numberGenerated = random.randint (1, 5)

numberEntered = int(raw_input("Enter a number between one and five: "))
match=False
while not match:

    if numberEntered > numberGenerated:
        print "Your guess was too high"
        numberEntered  =int(raw_input("Enter a number between one and five: "))

    elif numberEntered < numberGenerated:
        print "Your guess was too low"
        numberEntered  =int(raw_input("Enter a number between one and five: "))

    elif numberEntered == numberGenerated: 
        print "You're Correct!" 
        match = True
```

if you wrap everything in a function you could use the boolean value to start a new game recursively.

```
import random

def playGame():
    match=False
    numberGenerated = random.randint (1, 5)
    numberEntered  =int(raw_input("Enter a number between one and five: "))
    while not match:

        if numberEntered>numberGenerated:
            print "Your guess was too high"
            numberEntered  =int(raw_input("Enter a number between one and five: "))

        elif numberEntered<numberGenerated:
            print "Your guess was too low"
            numberEntered  =int(raw_input("Enter a number between one and five: "))

        elif numberEntered==numberGenerated: 
            print "You're Correct!" 
            match = True

    if match:
        again  =raw_input("type 'Y' to play again")
        if again.upper() == "Y":
            playGame()

playGame()
```